# How can i do dynamic filter to the listbox?

Tags: vba, filter, dynamic, listbox

I'm kinda new to this VBA and come across a problem with my project.
I'm seeking for some expert who can help me with this one.

I have a listbox and from filter textbox, and i want to filter the datas in listbox according to written text in textbox. Can you help me to write code for this application please?

expecting to solve this filter problem as soon as well[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Enp.png)

```
Option Explicit









Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
        CableInsu.List = Array("PVC", "Armored", "Screened", "Halogen Free")
        CableType.List = Sheets("Library").Range("B2:B30").Value
        CrossSection.List = Sheets("Library").Range("A2:A138").Value
        Status.List = Array("New", "Under Design", "For Construction", "As Built")
        VoltLevel.List = Sheets("Library").Range("I2:I5").Value
        
        FromGland.List = Sheets("Library").Range("D2:D24").Value
        ToGland.List = Sheets("Library").Range("E2:E24").Value
        FromGlandUsed.List = Sheets("Library").Range("F2:F24").Value
        ToGlandUsed.List = Sheets("Library").Range("G2:G24").Value
        RevDate.Text = Format(Now(), "DD/MM/YYYY")
        
        Dim shs As Worksheet
        Dim k As Integer
        Set shs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Drum")
        Me.DrumNo.Clear
        For k = 4 To shs.Range("C" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Me.DrumNo.AddItem shs.Range("C" & k).Value
        Me.DrumNo1.AddItem shs.Range("C" & k).Value
        Next k
        
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Dim i As Integer
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("equipment")
        Me.FromCode.Clear
        Me.ToCode.Clear
        For i = 4 To sh.Range("C" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Me.FromCode.AddItem sh.Range("C" & i).Value
        Me.ToCode.AddItem sh.Range("C" & i).Value
        Next i
        
        
       
        'Dim j As Integer
        'Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("equipment")
        'Me.ToCode.Clear
        'For j = 4 To sh.Range("C" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'Me.ToCode.AddItem sh.Range("C" & j).Value
        'Next j
       
        
        FromGlandThread.List = Array("16mm", "20mm", "Ex 16mm", "Ex 20mm", "Arm 16mm", "Arm 20mm")
        ToGlandThread.List = Array("16mm", "20mm", "Ex 16mm", "Ex 20mm", "Arm 16mm", "Arm 20mm")
        FromGlndUsedUs.List = Array("16mm", "20mm", "Ex 16mm", "Ex 20mm", "Arm 16mm", "Arm 20mm")
        ToGlndUsedUs.List = Array("16mm", "20mm", "Ex 16mm", "Ex 20mm", "Arm 16mm", "Arm 20mm")
        Call UserForm_Initialize
End Sub

'''''''''''''''''''' Save Button  '''''''''''''''''''

Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Registration")
        Dim lr As Long
        lr = sh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'''''''''''''''Validation'''''''''''''''

        If Me.CableID.Value = "" Then
           MsgBox "Please enter the Cable ID", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
           Exit Sub
        End If
        
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("B:B"), Me.ItemNo.Text) > 0 Then
           MsgBox "Cable Item No already exist!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Error"
           Exit Sub
        End If
        
'''''''''''''''''Add Data in Excel Sheet'''''''''''''
       
       If MsgBox("Do you want to add data to Database?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Question") = vbNo Then
           Exit Sub
        End If
       
       With sh
            .Cells(lr + 1, "B").Value = Me.ItemNo.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "C").Value = "0"
            .Cells(lr + 1, "D").Value = Me.RevDate.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "E").Value = Me.CableID.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "F").Value = Me.Voltage.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "G").Value = Me.VoltLevel.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "H").Value = Me.CableType.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "I").Value = Me.CrossSection.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "J").Value = Me.EngLen.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "K").Value = Me.FromCode.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "L").Value = Me.FromTitle.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "M").Value = Me.FromCompartment.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "N").Value = Me.FromGland.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "O").Value = Me.FromGlandThread.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "P").Value = Me.FromArea.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "Q").Value = Me.ToCode.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "R").Value = Me.ToTitle.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "S").Value = Me.ToCompartment.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "T").Value = Me.ToGland.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "U").Value = Me.ToGlandThread.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "V").Value = Me.ToArea.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "W").Value = Me.CableDesc.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "X").Value = Me.AvevaID.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "Y").Value = Me.Status.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "Z").Value = Me.Power.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "AA").Value = Me.PreLen.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "AB").Value = Me.SubSystem.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "AC").Value = Me.CableInsu.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "AD").Value = Me.Route.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "AE").Value = Me.DrumNo1.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "AF").Value = Me.ActLen.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "AG").Value = Me.DrumNo.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "AH").Value = Me.CablePullDate.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "AI").Value = Me.CablePullBy.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "AJ").Value = Me.CableTermDate.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "AK").Value = Me.CableTermBy.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "AL").Value = Me.FromGlandUsed.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "AM").Value = Me.FromGlndUsedUs.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "AN").Value = Me.ToGlandUsed.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "AO").Value = Me.ToGlndUsedUs.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "AP").Value = Me.Remarks.Value
           
           
            
       End With
       
'''''''''''''''Add Image''''''''''''''''
      
           
           Call UserForm_Initialize
       
End Sub

Private Sub ConsUpdate_Click()

        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Registration")
        Dim lr As Long
        lr = sh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim i As Long
        
If Me.CableID.Value = "DEL" Then
           MsgBox "You can't change the DELETED cable", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
           Exit Sub
        End If
        If MsgBox("Do you want to update the data?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Question") = vbNo Then
           Exit Sub
        End If
        
        
        For i = 4 To lr
            If sh.Cells(i, "B").Value = txtSearch.Text Then
            
               With sh
                    
                 sh.Cells(i, "AF").Value = Me.ActLen.Value
                 sh.Cells(i, "AG").Value = Me.DrumNo.Value
                 sh.Cells(i, "AH").Value = Me.CablePullDate.Value
                 sh.Cells(i, "AI").Value = Me.CablePullBy.Value
                 sh.Cells(i, "AJ").Value = Me.CableTermDate.Value
                 sh.Cells(i, "AK").Value = Me.CableTermBy.Value
                 sh.Cells(i, "AL").Value = Me.FromGlandUsed.Value
                 sh.Cells(i, "AM").Value = Me.FromGlndUsedUs.Value
                 sh.Cells(i, "AN").Value = Me.ToGlandUsed.Value
                 sh.Cells(i, "AO").Value = Me.ToGlndUsedUs.Value
                 sh.Cells(i, "AP").Value = Me.Remarks.Value
              
               End With
              
            End If
       Next i
       
     
        Call UserForm_Initialize
End Sub


Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
txtSearch.Text = ListBox1.Column(0)
Call cmdSearch_Click
End Sub

Private Sub PrintPullCard_Click()




        If Me.Status.Value = "New" Then
           MsgBox "Pull card only print at For Construction status", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
           Exit Sub
        End If
        
        If Me.Status.Value = "Under Design" Then
           MsgBox "Pull card only print at For Construction status", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
           Exit Sub
        End If
        
        If Me.Status.Value = "As Built" Then
           MsgBox "Pull card only print at For Construction status", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
           Exit Sub
        End If
        
      
  
        
        
 Dim sh As Worksheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Registration")
        Dim lr As Long
        lr = sh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim i As Long
        
     
        For i = 4 To lr
            If sh.Cells(i, "B").Value = txtSearch.Text Then
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("B1") = sh.Cells(i, "E").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("B5") = sh.Cells(i, "E").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("G1") = sh.Cells(i, "E").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("G5") = sh.Cells(i, "E").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("A12") = sh.Cells(i, "E").Value
              
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("B2") = sh.Cells(i, "R").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("B6") = sh.Cells(i, "R").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("G2") = sh.Cells(i, "R").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("G6") = sh.Cells(i, "R").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("H10") = sh.Cells(i, "R").Value
              
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("B3") = sh.Cells(i, "K").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("B7") = sh.Cells(i, "K").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("G3") = sh.Cells(i, "K").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("G7") = sh.Cells(i, "K").Value
              
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("B4") = sh.Cells(i, "N").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("B8") = sh.Cells(i, "N").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("G4") = sh.Cells(i, "N").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("G8") = sh.Cells(i, "N").Value
              
              'Sheets("PullCard").Range("G8") = sh.Cells(i, "N").Value  DESCRÝPTÝON
              'BENDÝNG RADÝUS
              'VENDOR DRUM NO
              
              
              'from
              
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("C15") = sh.Cells(i, "J").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("D15") = sh.Cells(i, "K").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("C16") = sh.Cells(i, "L").Value
              
              'to
              
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("C17") = sh.Cells(i, "M").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("D17") = sh.Cells(i, "N").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("C18") = sh.Cells(i, "O").Value
              
              'pulling
              
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("B30") = sh.Cells(i, "S").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("D30") = sh.Cells(i, "T").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("F30") = sh.Cells(i, "Q").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("H30") = sh.Cells(i, "I").Value
              Sheets("PullCard").Range("A23") = sh.Cells(i, "P").Value
              
               End If
        Next i
        
      Sheets("PullCard").PrintOut Copies:=3, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
End Sub



Private Sub Status_Change()

If Status.Value = "For Construction" Then
                       
                     RevNo.Value = 0
                     End If
End Sub

Private Sub FromCode_Change()

        Dim shm As Worksheet
        Set shm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Equipment")
        Dim lr As Long
        lr = shm.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim g As Long
        For g = 4 To lr
        If shm.Cells(g, "C").Value = FromCode.Text Then
        FromTitle = shm.Cells(g, "E").Value
        FromArea = shm.Cells(g, "F").Value
        End If
        Next g
        Call UserForm_Initialize

End Sub





Private Sub ToCode_Change()


 Dim sh As Worksheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Equipment")
        Dim lr As Long
        lr = sh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim i As Long
        
     
        For i = 4 To lr
            If sh.Cells(i, "C").Value = ToCode.Text Then
              ToTitle = sh.Cells(i, "E").Value
              ToArea = sh.Cells(i, "F").Value
                End If
        Next i
          
               
 Call UserForm_Initialize

End Sub


'''''''''''''''''''''Initialization'''''''''''''''
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()



'Dim shx As Worksheet
'Set shx = Sheets("Drum")
'Dim i As Long
'For i = 4 To shx.Range("I1000").End(xlUp).Row
'If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("I4", "I" & i), sh.Cells(i, 9)) = 1 Then
'Me.ComboBox5.AddItem sh.Cells(i, 9)
'End If
'Next i


    Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Registration")
Dim lr As Long
lr = Sheets("Registration").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row



ListBox1.ColumnCount = 40
ListBox1.ColumnHeads = True
ListBox1.ColumnWidths = ("50,50,80,60,50,50,60,80,50,90,200,90,60,60,90,90,200,90,60,60,90,100,50,80,80,50,80,80,250,60,50,60,80,100,80,100,80,80,80,80,200")

ListBox1.RowSource = "Registration!B4:AO" & lr







       
        
        With ItemNo
             .Value = Format(Val(Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) + 1, "0000")
             .Enabled = True
        End With
        
        Me.CablePullDate.Value = "DD-MM-YYYY"
        Me.CableTermDate.Value = "DD-MM-YYYY"
        Me.CablePullDate.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
         Me.CableTermDate.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        
       
        
        CableID.SetFocus
End Sub











''''''''''''''''Reset Button''''''''''''''''''''''''

Private Sub cmdReset_Click()
        If MsgBox("Do you want to Reset this form?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Question") = vbYes Then
           Unload Me
           Registration_Form.Show
        End If
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''Exit Button''''''''''''''''''''''

Private Sub cmdExit_Click()
        If MsgBox("Do you want to exit this form?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Question") = vbYes Then
           Unload Me
        End If
End Sub

'''''''''''''''''''''''''SearchButton''''''''''''''''''''''

Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Registration")
        Dim lr As Long
        lr = sh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim i As Long
        
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("B:B"), Me.txtSearch.Text) = 0 Then
           MsgBox "No match found!!!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Error"
          
           Call UserForm_Initialize
           txtSearch.SetFocus
           Exit Sub
        End If
        
        For i = 4 To lr
            If sh.Cells(i, "B").Value = txtSearch.Text Then
            
                            
                            
                        
            RevNo = sh.Cells(i, "C").Value
            RevDate = sh.Cells(i, "D").Value
            CableID = sh.Cells(i, "E").Value
            Voltage = sh.Cells(i, "F").Value
            VoltLevel = sh.Cells(i, "G").Value
            CableType = sh.Cells(i, "H").Value
            CrossSection = sh.Cells(i, "I").Value
            EngLen = sh.Cells(i, "J").Value
            FromCode = sh.Cells(i, "K").Value
            FromTitle = sh.Cells(i, "L").Value
            FromCompartment = sh.Cells(i, "M").Value
            FromGland = sh.Cells(i, "N").Value
            FromGlandThread = sh.Cells(i, "O").Value
            FromArea = sh.Cells(i, "P").Value
            ToCode = sh.Cells(i, "Q").Value
            ToTitle = sh.Cells(i, "R").Value
            ToCompartment = sh.Cells(i, "S").Value
            ToGland = sh.Cells(i, "T").Value
            ToGlandThread = sh.Cells(i, "U").Value
            ToArea = sh.Cells(i, "V").Value
            CableDesc = sh.Cells(i, "W").Value
            AvevaID = sh.Cells(i, "X").Value
            Status = sh.Cells(i, "Y").Value
            Power = sh.Cells(i, "Z").Value
            PreLen = sh.Cells(i, "AA").Value
            SubSystem = sh.Cells(i, "AB").Value
            CableInsu = sh.Cells(i, "AC").Value
            Route = sh.Cells(i, "AD").Value
            DrumNo1 = sh.Cells(i, "AE").Value
            ActLen = sh.Cells(i, "AF").Value
            DrumNo = sh.Cells(i, "AG").Value
            CablePullDate = sh.Cells(i, "AH").Value
            CablePullBy = sh.Cells(i, "AI").Value
            CableTermDate = sh.Cells(i, "AJ").Value
            CableTermBy = sh.Cells(i, "AK").Value
            FromGlandUsed = sh.Cells(i, "AL").Value
            FromGlndUsedUs = sh.Cells(i, "AM").Value
            ToGlandUsed = sh.Cells(i, "AN").Value
            ToGlndUsedUs = sh.Cells(i, "AO").Value
            Remarks = sh.Cells(i, "AP").Value
                            
            End If
        Next i
        
End Sub

'''''''''''''''''''''Update Button'''''''''''''''''''''''''

Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Registration")
        Dim lr As Long
        lr = sh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim i As Long
        
'''''''''''''''' Validation '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        If Me.CableID.Value = "" Then
           MsgBox "Please enter the Cable ID", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
           Exit Sub
        End If
    
    
        If Me.CableID.Value = "DEL" Then
           MsgBox "You can't change the DELETED cable", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
           Exit Sub
        End If
        

'''''''''''''''Update data to excel file '''''''''''''''''''''
        If MsgBox("Do you want to update the data?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Question") = vbNo Then
           Exit Sub
        End If
        
        For i = 4 To lr
            If sh.Cells(i, "B").Value = txtSearch.Text Then
            
               With sh
                 
               
                       
                       
                       
            sh.Cells(i, "C").Value = Me.RevNo.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "D").Value = Me.RevDate.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "E").Value = Me.CableID.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "F").Value = Me.Voltage.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "G").Value = Me.VoltLevel.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "H").Value = Me.CableType.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "I").Value = Me.CrossSection.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "J").Value = Me.EngLen.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "K").Value = Me.FromCode.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "L").Value = Me.FromTitle.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "M").Value = Me.FromCompartment.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "N").Value = Me.FromGland.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "O").Value = Me.FromGlandThread.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "P").Value = Me.FromArea.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "Q").Value = Me.ToCode.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "R").Value = Me.ToTitle.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "S").Value = Me.ToCompartment.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "T").Value = Me.ToGland.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "U").Value = Me.ToGlandThread.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "V").Value = Me.ToArea.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "W").Value = Me.CableDesc.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "X").Value = Me.AvevaID.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "Y").Value = Me.Status.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "Z").Value = Me.Power.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "AA").Value = Me.PreLen.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "AB").Value = Me.SubSystem.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "AC").Value = Me.CableInsu.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "AD").Value = Me.Route.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "AE").Value = Me.DrumNo1.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "AF").Value = Me.ActLen.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "AG").Value = Me.DrumNo.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "AH").Value = Me.CablePullDate.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "AI").Value = Me.CablePullBy.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "AJ").Value = Me.CableTermDate.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "AK").Value = Me.CableTermBy.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "AL").Value = Me.FromGlandUsed.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "AM").Value = Me.FromGlndUsedUs.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "AN").Value = Me.ToGlandUsed.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "AO").Value = Me.ToGlndUsedUs.Value
            sh.Cells(i, "AP").Value = Me.Remarks.Value
            
                       
                       
                       
                       
                       
                       
                       
                       
                       
                       
                       
                       
                       
                       
                       If Status.Value = "New" Then
                       
                       sh.Cells(i, "C").Value = "AA"
                       
                       ElseIf Status.Value = "For Construction" Then
                       
                       sh.Cells(i, "C").Value = Me.RevNo.Value + 0.1
                       
                       ElseIf Status.Value = "Under Design" Then
                       
                        sh.Cells(i, "C").Value = "B"
                        
                       ElseIf Status.Value = "As Built" Then
                        
                        sh.Cells(i, "C").Value = "X"
                        
                       
                       End If
                       
                    
                         
             'If Drum!Used.Value > Drum!Leng.Value Then
'MsgBox "DRUM LENGTH ERROR!!!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Error"
'End If

               End With
              
            End If
       Next i
       
     
        Call UserForm_Initialize
        


End Sub

'''''''''''''Delete Button''''''''''''''''''''''''

Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()


  
 Dim sh As Worksheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Registration")
        Dim lr As Long
        lr = sh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim i As Long
        
'''''''''''''''' Validation '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        If Me.CableID.Value = "" Then
           MsgBox "Please enter the Cable ID", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
           Exit Sub
        End If
    
        

'''''''''''''''Update data to excel file '''''''''''''''''''''
        If MsgBox("Do you want to DELETE the data?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Question") = vbNo Then
           Exit Sub
        End If
        
        For i = 4 To lr
            If sh.Cells(i, "B").Value = txtSearch.Text Then
            
               With sh
                 
                 sh.Cells(i, "C").Value = "DEL"
                 sh.Cells(i, "D").Value = "DEL"
                 sh.Cells(i, "E").Value = "DEL"
                 sh.Cells(i, "F").Value = "DEL"
                 sh.Cells(i, "G").Value = "DEL"
                 sh.Cells(i, "H").Value = "DEL"
                 sh.Cells(i, "I").Value = "DEL"
                       sh.Cells(i, "J").Value = "DEL"
                        sh.Cells(i, "K").Value = "DEL"
                       sh.Cells(i, "L").Value = "DEL"
                      sh.Cells(i, "M").Value = "DEL"
                     sh.Cells(i, "N").Value = "DEL"
                    sh.Cells(i, "O").Value = "DEL"
                   sh.Cells(i, "P").Value = "DEL"
                 sh.Cells(i, "Q").Value = "DEL"
                 sh.Cells(i, "R").Value = "DEL"
                sh.Cells(i, "S").Value = "DEL"
               sh.Cells(i, "T").Value = "DEL"
              sh.Cells(i, "U").Value = "DEL"
              sh.Cells(i, "V").Value = "DEL"
               sh.Cells(i, "W").Value = "DEL"
                sh.Cells(i, "X").Value = "DEL"
                 sh.Cells(i, "Y").Value = "DEL"
                  sh.Cells(i, "Z").Value = "DEL"
                   sh.Cells(i, "AA").Value = "DEL"
                    sh.Cells(i, "AB").Value = "DEL"
                     sh.Cells(i, "AC").Value = "DEL"
                      sh.Cells(i, "AD").Value = "DEL"
                       sh.Cells(i, "AE").Value = "DEL"
                        sh.Cells(i, "AF").Value = "DEL"
                         sh.Cells(i, "AG").Value = "DEL"
                          sh.Cells(i, "AL").Value = "DEL"
                         sh.Cells(i, "AM").Value = "DEL"
                         
             
               End With
              
            End If
       Next i
       
     
        Call UserForm_Initialize


End Sub








Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
EquipmentList.Show
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Termination.Show

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Progress.Show
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
Drum.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: This code fragment is to long for a question. Can you shorten the code to get a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? What is your specific problem?

Comment: `sh.Cells(i, "C").Value = "DEL"`  etc et  etc could be simpler as `sh.Rows(i).range("C1:AG1").Value = "DEL"`

Comment: `sh.Cells(i, "C").Value = "DEL"....sh.Cells(i, "C").Value = "DEL"` could be simpler as `sh.Rows(i).range("C1:AG1,AL1:AM1").Value = "DEL"`

Answer (score 1):

As @Shrotter says, the code you have supplied is much too long to re-factor, so I'm providing you with the generic code for a TextBox to be used as a text filter for a ListBox.

In this example, I'm assuming you have a UserForm with a TextBox called TextBox1, a ListBox with 1 column called ListBox1, and Variant holding a 1-dimensional array of strings called aValues. Obviously, you will need to update these names for your code.

In the code-behind of the UserForm, add this Sub which clears and then adds items to the ListBox depending on whether the name of the ListBox item partially matches what is in the TextBox

```
Sub UpdateListBox()
    Dim i As Long, text As String
    text = TextBox1.text
    ListBox1.Clear
    For i = LBound(aValues) To UBound(aValues)
        If Len(text) = 0 Or InStr(1, aValues(i), text, vbTextCompare) Then ' use vbBinaryCompare if required for your needs
            ListBox1.AddItem
            ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 0) = aValues(i)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

You then need to call this from two places ... the Change event handler for the TextBox eg

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    UpdateListBox
End Sub
```

And when the UserForm is first being created (but before it is shown ie before you call `Show`) so eg from the UserForm_Activate event handler, though the key is that `aValues` must have been populated before you do this